# What specifies semi colon as statement separators on CRTQMQRY and STRQMQRY commands

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, control-language

When running multiline SQL code with semi colon as sql statement separators the following errors:

```
CRTQMQRY QMQRY(MYPGMLIB/MYSQL) SRCFILE(MYLIB/QSQLSRC)
STRQMQRY QMQRY(MYPGMLIB/MYSQL)
```

Whereas the following works:

```
RUNSQLSTM SRCFILE(MYPGMLIB/QSQLSRC) SRCMBR(MYSQL) COMMIT(*NONE)
```

I've googled the options on CRTQMQRY and STRQMQRY but cannot find anything that specifies statement separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query Manager (QM) does not support multiple statements per member.

Use RUNSQLSTM.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple queries are needed in a collected group of statements, you can use RUNSQLSTM. If they have logical connections, you might code them into a DB2 stored procedure.

If you want to do them with Query Management, e.g., to be run with the STRQMQRY command, you'll need to create a QM PROC. See the [**DB2 Universal Database for iSeries Query Management Programming manual**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/books/sc415703.pdf) (PDF). Although QM can be powerful,very few learn about QM PROCs under DB2 for i. QM to that level is more common on mainframes and even on PCs.

Comment: It was the [greatest comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/196153/25823) ever left on the Internet. I still do not know who Vern is, though.